# twitteR: Converting lookupUser list into a single data frame

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to generate a data frame from the list generated by lookupUsers. Consider the following code snippet,

```
library(twitteR)
api_key <- "xx"
api_secret <- "xx"
access_token <- "xx"
access_token_secret <- "xx"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

listofusers <- c("POTUS", "FBI", "StackExchange")
userlist <- lookupUsers(listofusers)
```

It is generating a list of 3 objects. How can I convert it into a usable data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation of the `lookupUsers` function, the output of the call is: '*a list of user objects, sorted in the order of the users argument, with names being the particular element of users that it matches to*'.

If you then jump to the documentation of the user class (still in the twitteR package) you can see that one of the methods for this class is the `toDataFrame` method.

So you can simply iterate through your list, calling the method in order to obtain your restructured dataframe:

```
to_df = lapply(userlist, function(tmp_user){
    tmp_user$toDataFrame()
})
to_df = dplyr::bind_rows(to_df)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked perfectly. I found an easier solution though. We can use `twListToDF(to_df)` function directly.